# Can I use express-session with React for auth?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm pretty new to authentication and I was wondering if there is a way to use express-session with React for login authentication. When using React Router, I can't use redircets in the server therefore I can't or don't know how to authenticate the user that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't as you need express for express-session. So, you need to set up a route on your express server.js file passing express-session middleware and you can use express-session APIs on your server.js for auth then you can setup your react route pointing to this server route.